# Make rotate image only by handler, but not on image itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, rotation

I would like to rotate the image by handler only, but not on image itself. 
I don't need to rotate the image while click and rotate on image. Please don't prescribe me to use Jquery UI rotatable-> Reason: Now i resize the image using Jquery UI resizable. Resize not works after rotating the image using Jquery UI rotatable.
So now i need to rotate the image by this handler only without using Jquery UI rotatable. Please help me to works this fine... Thanks in Advance..

```
<div>
    <div id="image_box">
    <div id="rotate_handle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My code in [Jsfiddle..!](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/npmtfLt6/9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JavaScript, bind the `.mousedown` to the handle, not the whole `image_box`.
For example:

`dial.find("#rotate_handle").mousedown(function(e) {
  ...
});`